# Lost Passwords for eToken Java 72K

Tags: passwords, token

I have a USB token called eToken Java 72k, but there is a problem: I don't remember the user and administrator passwords.

Who knows if there is a way to format this device completely so that all passwords and data are erased, without the password itself.

There is specs for a token:

```
eToken Category: Physical

Reader name: Aladdin Token JC 0

Serial number: 0x0229f174

Total Memory: 73728

Free space on eToken smart card: 32767

Hardware version: 4.30

Firmware version: Not applicable

Smartcard ID: 02 29 f1 74

Product name: eToken PRO Java 72K OS755

Model: Token JC

Smart Card Type: Java Card

OS version: eToken Java Applet 1.1.25

Mask version: 8.5

Color: Purple

Supported key size: 2048

User Password: Present

User password attempts - Remaining: 0

User password attempts - Max: 15

Administrator Password: Present

Administrator password attempts - Remaining: 0

Administrator password attempts - Max: 15
```

Comment: Does the manual for the device contain any information on how to wipe the device without the password? How confident are you the device can even be reused after data has been written to it?

Comment: According to the manual, **all data on the device is lost** after spending all the attempts. Yours show 0 ramaining attepts both for user and admin passwords so there's nothing left. Why are you asking?

Comment: @Ramhound, I tried to wipe using default methods, but it requeres admin password that I dont have

Comment: @ChanganAuto, I want to Set a new password but i cant because device is locked

Comment: That's how it is supposed to be. Users **must** remember the password.

Comment: @ТимофейБеляев -I will repeat my previous comment, in my experience a nearly identical product, once the device is locked because the wrong user passwords was provided, it can only be unlocked with the Administrator password. Are you simply trying to avoid purchasing a new smartcard? One cannot typically reprogram smartcards once the certificate has been published to them. These cards are not designed to be reused multiple times.

Comment: @Ramhound Ok, thanks for trying to help me, I thought I can resurrect my old device.